# Segfaul out from debugger

Tags: c, file, gdb

I have a big problem with this program that simulates a database, everytime that i call the Database_set function, it return segfaul, but when i use gdb for debugging, everythings runs fine.

With more test, i found that everything work well during debugging if i create a new database (a file used for store datas) without reusing the already created databases, if i do things in this way, the call to Database_set won't return segfaul.

Out from debugger, this trick doesn't work and i get segfaul every time i try to access at line 122 `addr->set`, even if `addr` isn't a `NULL` pointer, because the previous call to `malloc` doesn't get error.

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char *name;
    char *email;
};

struct Database {
    int MAX_DATA;
    int MAX_ROWS;
    struct Address *rows;
};

struct Connection {
    FILE *file;
    struct Database *db;
};

void die(const char *message)
{
    if(errno) {
        perror(message);
    } else {
        printf("ERROR: %s\n", message);
    }

    exit(1);
}

void Address_print(struct Address *addr)
{
    printf("%d %s %s\n",
            addr->id, addr->name, addr->email);
}


void Database_load(struct Connection *conn)
{
    int rc = fread(conn->db, sizeof(struct Database), 1, conn->file);
    if(rc != 1) die("Failed to load database.");
}


struct Connection *Database_open(const char *filename, char mode)
{
    struct Connection *conn = malloc(sizeof(struct Connection));
    if(!conn) die("Memory error");

    conn->db = malloc(sizeof(struct Database));
    if(!conn->db) die("Memory error");

    if(mode == 'c') {
        conn->file = fopen(filename, "w");
    } else {
        conn->file = fopen(filename, "r+");

        if(conn->file) {
            Database_load(conn);
        }
    }

    if(!conn->file) die("Failed to open the file");

    return conn;
}

void Database_close(struct Connection *conn)
{
    if(conn) {
        if(conn->file) fclose(conn->file);
        if(conn->db) free(conn->db);
        free(conn);
    }
}

void Database_write(struct Connection *conn)
{
    rewind(conn->file);

    int rc = fwrite(conn->db, sizeof(struct Database), 1, conn->file);
    if(rc != 1) die("Failed to write database.");

    rc =fflush(conn->file);
    if(rc == -1) die("Cannot flush database.");
}

void Database_create(struct Connection *conn)
{
    printf("Please, insert max database rows limit .....");
    scanf("%d",&conn->db->MAX_ROWS);

    int i = 0;

    conn->db->rows = malloc(sizeof(struct Address)*conn->db->MAX_ROWS);
    if (!conn->db->rows) die("Memory error !");

    for (i = 0; i < conn->db->MAX_ROWS; i++) {

        /* struct Address addr = {.id = i, .set = 0};
        conn->db->rows[i] = addr; */

        conn->db->rows[i].id = 1;
        conn->db->rows[i].set = 0;
    }
}

void Database_set(struct Connection *conn, int id, const char *name, const char *email)
{

    printf("Please, insert max data limit ....");
     scanf("%d", &conn->db->MAX_DATA);


    struct Address *addr = &conn->db->rows[id];

    if(addr->set) die("Already set, delete it first");

    addr->set = 1;

    addr->name = malloc(conn->db->MAX_DATA);
    if(!addr->name) die("Memory error !");

    char *res = strcpy(addr->name, name);
    if(!res) die("Name copy failed");


    addr->email =malloc(conn->db->MAX_DATA);
    if(!addr->email) die("Memory error !");

    res = strcpy(addr->email, email);
    if(!res) die("Email copy failed");


}

void Database_get(struct Connection *conn, int id)
{
    struct Address *addr = &conn->db->rows[id];

    if(addr->set) {
        Address_print(addr);
    } else {
        die("ID is not set");
    }
}

void Database_delete(struct Connection *conn, int id)
{
    conn->db->rows[id].id = id;
    conn->db->rows[id].set = 0;
}

void Database_list(struct Connection *conn)
{
    int i = 0;
    struct Database *db = conn->db;

    for(i = 0; i < conn->db->MAX_ROWS; i++) {
        struct Address *cur = &db->rows[i];

        if(cur->set) {
            Address_print(cur);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if(argc < 3) die("USAGE: ex17 <dbfile> <action> [action params]");

    char *filename = argv[1];
    char action = argv[2][0];

    struct Connection *conn = Database_open(filename, action);

    int id = 0;

    if (action != 'c') 
    {
        if (argc > 3) id = atoi(argv[4]);
        if (id >= conn->db->MAX_ROWS) die("There's not that many records.");
    }

    switch(action) {
        case 'c':
            Database_create(conn);
            Database_write(conn);
            break;

        case 'g':
            if(argc != 4) die("Need an id to get");
            Database_get(conn, id);
            break;

        case 's':
            if(argc != 6) die("Need id, name, email to set");

            Database_set(conn, id, argv[4], argv[5]);
            Database_write(conn);
            break;

        case 'd':
            if(argc != 4) die("Need id to delete");

            Database_delete(conn, id);
            Database_write(conn);
            break;

        case 'l':
            Database_list(conn);
            break;
        default:
            die("Invalid action, only: c=create, g=get, s=set, d=del, l=list");
    }

    Database_close(conn);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You always dereference `conn` without checking if it's `NULL` and `conn->db->MAX_ROWS` is bad style all over the expression, first keep UPPER CASE IDENTIFIERS for macros only, and second do not use two indidrections in the same expression ... if `db == NULL` there you go ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your basic mistake here is the fact, that you assume you can write/read your "database" by doing this:

```
    int rc = fwrite(conn->db, sizeof(struct Database), 1, conn->file);
```

As your struct Database also includes this field:

```
struct Address *rows;
```

It cannot be done this way. This writes a pointer (something like 0xc2b82200) into your file, instead of your array itself. When you try to load your file, you set pointer back to the same value, but as this is new sesion, this now points to probably some unallocated memory page which gives you a segfault.

You need to write your "table" row by row.